# Microsoft application registration portal not accept standard http Redirect URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, alexa-skills-kit

I am registering a Native application in the Microsoft [application registration portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-app-registration) with the goal of giving it delegate permission to my separately registered Azure Web API.  As I understand, this is the [normal setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-flows#mobile-and-native-apps) for desktop or mobile application, because an authorization UI cannot be directly shown to the user.

Since my application is an Amazon Alexa skill, I must use the mandated Alexa [redirect links](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/account-linking/configure-authorization-code-grant.html).  Within the Microsoft application registration portal these links need to be placed in the custom redirect URIs section of my native application platform (See image below).  It would like me to use a URI like "msalaaaaa-bbbb-ccc-dddd-111111111111://auth", which I guess works for Azure mobile and desktop native applications.

Why does the portal not permit a http URI?  When will this feature be implemented or do I have a miss-understanding?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft do not support transmitting tokens over unsecured channel. Currently, apps that are registered in the Application Registration Portal are restricted to a limited set of redirect URI values. The redirect URI for web apps and services must begin with the scheme https, and all redirect URI values must share a single DNS domain. For example, you cannot register a web app that has one of these redirect URIs:

https://login-east.contoso.com

https://login-west.contoso.com

Comment: My issue is when I add a Native platform and not a Web API.  The Native Application (See image above) will not accept any https URL, but instead requires the path to start with "msalaaaa-bbb-eeee://{domain}/{path}".  Since my native app is for Amazon Alexa it has a mandated https authentication URL.  Is this is a permanent restriction (roadmap), because this .NET Amazon [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/12/09/amazon-alexa-skills-authenticated-by-azure-active-directory-and-backed-by-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api-hosted-on-azure/) works with Azure endpoint v1.0.